# Существуют ли альтернативы Pusher и Redis для event broadcasting Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Добрый день!

Мне необходимо реализовать сервис event broadcasting между бэкэндом и фронтендом. Соответственно, необходима библиотека с этим функционалом. Поддерживающиеся из коробки Pusher и Redis не устраивают по ряду причин. Подскажите, существуют ли альтернативы и если да, то можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на Github этих библиотек. Самое важное, чтобы можно было отловить с помощью Laravel Echo. Сложность значения не имеет.

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: "по ряду причин" - и как отвечающие угадают, что именно вам нужно, если вы не называете причины?

Comment: @svgrafov, причины: только PHP + MySQL, VPS сервер. Заказчик не хочет, чтобы скрипт опрашивал сервер, хочет, чтобы уведомления о событиях сразу приходили клиенту приложения. В данной ситуации, я не назвал эти причины, потому что они особого значения не имеют.

Comment: А вы сами то это как то представляете?